# Spring singleton bean

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I know this question may sound naive, but I have a confusion regarding the scope of bean in web application.
I know that for every request a new thread is spawned by the container similarly in case of a spring web application a new thread is spawned for every request, then why it is suggested to define my controller, service as singleton, shouldn't the scope of these beans be prototype, because each request i.e. thread will have their own instance of controller, service to work with.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: And, I guess you should check the difference between request and prototype scope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480005/spring-request-and-prototype-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gottalovedev.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/bean-scope/

Give this a read. I'm sure it would help.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link, it answers my question.

Comment: you're welcome!! In case you are doubtful about any other topics in spring/java, please place a request and I'll write a post on that topic.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a huge amount of overhead. There's no reason why each request needs its own service bean if you make your code properly thread-safe, which usually just means not keeping any per-request state on the bean.

Comment: Object instantiation is fast. The overhead of instantiating a reasonable service or controller generally isn't a performance issue, and there are fewer thread safety concerns. For services in particular there's just no *reason* to have multiple copies (in general), for controllers the arguments aren't as clear-cut.

Comment: @DaveNewton Instantiation is fast. Wiring isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Even though a new thread is created (or re-used depending on the configuration), the controller and service instances are re-used. If the controllers and services are designed well, they can be stateless with respect to the request and immutable, which will make them thread-safe. It would also lead to far less object creations when their state is not going to change after their creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this really depends whether you need to store any state in your bean. Usually, I write my singletons so that they contain no state inside of it and are only used to compute business logic. Without state needing to be managed, then it is acceptable to have all threads share that one singleton instance.