# What should be the appropriate scope for Struts 2 Action class beans managed by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, struts2, thread-safety, global-variables

In a Spring managed Struts 2 application, the **HttpServletRequest** objects are stored as a **global variable** inside the Action classes.
After doing some research I found that by default Struts Action classes are thread safe as they are instantiated for every request, but in the scenario described above, the Struts Action classes are configured as Spring beans without mentioning the bean scope(So by default they are singletons). I think this is a recipe for a disaster, so I was searching for a fix and I found the following in the official Struts 2 Spring integration example below:

```
<bean id="editService" class="org.apache.struts.edit.service.EditServiceInMemory"/>

<bean id="editAction" class="org.apache.struts.edit.action.EditAction" scope="prototype">

    <property name="editService" ref="editService" />

</bean>
```

Here the scope is set to prototype but I thing it should be request as the action class needs to instantiated for every Http request. Please tell me whether my understanding is correct and if it is the correct solution, other than instantiating the request objects as local variables.

I had found the following question in stack overflow but I want to know in terms of Struts 2:
[Spring Request and Prototype Scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480005/spring-request-and-prototype-scope)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Request and Prototype Scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480005/spring-request-and-prototype-scope). I think that pretty much tells you what you want to know.  With request scoped you will get the same bean instance for the lifetime of the httprequest.  So it depends on your use case:  like do you have filters along with your actions where you might want to share state.

Comment: Hi Robert, that question answers the difference between the request and prototype bean, but I wanted to know in a struts managed web application what should be the correct scope between request and prototype.

Comment: @RobertMoskal: We don't have filters, but we are extrating the data from the request and doing security checks inside the action classes. As per my understanding the correct way to instantiate would be to declare the action classes in request scope but in the offical doc it is given as prototype so there lies my confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post explains pretty clearly how the two work: [Spring Request and Prototype Scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480005/spring-request-and-prototype-scope)

I would say that if your app only uses simple actions, it really doesn't matter which you use.  If you are using filters or struts interceptors and want to hold state between different steps in the request pipeline, then you must use request scoped beans.  Otherwise it again doesn't matter.

I would probably use prototype based beans when request based ones weren't absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Actually we have a parent abstract action class where the global request variable is declared and it is extended and implemented by all the action classes in our app. we are only sharing the state(the request object) between different action classes which refer to that single request object declared globally in the parent action class. So what I understand is, to fix this issue the action bean should be declared in a request scope because the request state is shared by a chain of action classes.

Comment: It you have a class hierarchy then you really only have a single class that is instantiated and not a chain, so I still think you don't need to use a request scoped bean, But no harm if you do.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Why do you say that `no harm if you do`? You never know a disaster when you use a request scope of Struts2 controllers that are also a data beans, but controllers themselves.

Comment: That's why I said in the simple case, but I will amend!