# Difference between ProxyMode of PROTOTYPE and REQUEST scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I created a simple *Spring Boot* project. In the project, I created 2 interfaces which are implemented by 2 service class. One service class is annotated with Prototype scope while another is annotated with Request scope.
Both the service class have proxy mode `ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES`

In my Controller class, I am autowiring both the Service class and simply printing out the object. Both are giving me different references every time I make an HTTP request. Why do we need to set the scope as `REQUEST` if we can achieve the same thing using `PROTOTYPE` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definitions**
If a bean has PROTOTYPE scope, the Spring IoC container creates a new bean instance every time a request for that bean is made. If a bean has REQUEST scope, every HTTP request will have it's own instance of the bean.

**Example**
In your example, if you wanted the same reference across the entire lifecycle of your HTTP request, you would want to use REQUEST scope.

I found a nice illustration of the differences between REQUEST and PROTOTYPE scoped beans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6991971/14160700).

**[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)**